# Second new object != class.this in AtomicReference

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I'm reading some android service code which handles gps coordinates and sets AtomicReference with new Object for 1 time :

```
public class SingleLocationUpdateService extends ServicePart {
 private final AtomicReference<GPSUpdater> currentUpdater = new AtomicReference<>();
 @Override
protected boolean onStart() {
    lastSaverModeOn = mService.getSettings().getRootSettings().isSaverModeOn();
    if (mService.getSettings().getRootSettings().isStopMileageInWorkOn()) {
        if (lastSaverModeOn) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    singleUpdateSeconds = mService.getSettings().getRootSettings().getGpsRareUpdateSeconds();
    ***currentUpdater.set(new GPSUpdater());***
    mService.getExecutor().schedule(currentUpdater.get(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return true;
}
```

Then sheduler executes this:

```
private class GPSUpdater implements Runnable, LocationListener {

 @Override
    public void run() {
        if (!isCurrentRunning()) {
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting single location update");
        final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mService.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this, Looper.getMainLooper());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to request single location update", t);
        }
        reschedule();
    }

    private boolean isCurrentRunning() {
        return isStarted() && currentUpdater.get() == GPSUpdater.this;
    }

    private void reschedule() {
        final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) mService.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);

        final GPSUpdater next = new GPSUpdater();

        if (isStarted() && currentUpdater.compareAndSet(GPSUpdater.this, next)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Rescheduling single location updater");
            mService.getExecutor().schedule(next, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }
```

In debugger if I run  currentUpdater.compareAndSet(GPSUpdater.this, next) for 1 time it returns true, so means new GPSUpdater(which was set in onStart()) == GPSUpdater.this. Then AtomicReference is set to next. But next is also new GPSUpdater. But if u eveluate currentUpdater.compareAndSet(GPSUpdater.this, next) 2 time, it will return false. So for 2 time new GPSUpdater != GPSUpdater.this. How can it be explained correctly? If I create 2 new object references - only the first one will be equal to its class reference? Why? Thx in advance.

Comment: Can't you narrow down the question and post an [mcve] it's pretty hard to read/understand *as is*

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two different objects of the Class GPSUpdater by calling for each of them `new GPSUpdater()`. Therefore if you want to compare two objects you should better use the equals() method. And if you wrote the GPSUpdate Class by yourself you may need to overwrite the `equals()` method to produce appropriate results. By this I mean that equals should return true if you define two objects to be equal. 
If you use the `==` Operator to check if two objects are the same only there reference is checked not the real "content" of the objects